# $_POST not being set

Tags: php, post, submit, checkbox

does anyone have any idea why `$_POST` not being set??

here is some of the code.

```
<form method="post" name="form" id="clientForm" action="">
    <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Delete_Checked"/>
    <?php if ($i%2){ ?> class="even"<?php } ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="doc[]" value="<?php echo $document->doID; ?>"/>
    <?php $i++; } ?>
</form>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['sub']) == 'Delete_Checked'){
        print_r($_POST['sub']); // nothing gets print.......
    }
?>
```

i must be overlooking something.

Comment: What is the `action` attribute of the `<form>` element?

Comment: Your code starting at "if (isset(..." is outside the <?php tags. It won't get executed at all.

Comment: @thilo: sorry, i just missed the <?php ?> when i wrote the code here. i will edit it.

Comment: Make sure to copy and paste your actual code - if you type it, you might include subtle differences that will lead people down the wrong path.

Comment: I don't see any field named "sub" in this form.

Comment: @Wesley, it's the submit button he's trying to print out, not the checkbox. It's name is "sub". @Phphelp, try print_r($_POST) and see what that array looks like.

Comment: `isset($_POST['sub']) == 'Delete_Checked')` will always return FALSE as isset returns TRUE/FALSE. @Thilo, I don't see any submit button in this code, how do you know "sub" is not another checkbox? Already went over the var_dump() tactic and he said the entire $_POST array is empty.

Comment: 2nd line from the top. <input type='submit' name='sub' ... />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (isset($_POST['sub']) == 'Delete_Checked'){
```

This is not how it should be written. It will only work by accident.

What the author wanted to write was:

```
if (isset($_POST['sub']) && ($_POST['sub'] == 'Delete_Checked')) {
```

I would personally leave out the whole `isset` part, because that's exactly what's obstructing your assessment of the cause.

Comment: Hey mario , Am getting error as `ReferenceError: $_POST is not defined` How can i solve that

Comment: @Becky sounds like PHP misplaced in JavaScript context, see [Uncaught ReferenceError: $\_POST is not defined](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32712097)

Answer (score 4):

If the checkbox is not checked when submitted, it won't be in the $_POST array.

$_POST itself is always set. Try this instead when you need to see everything it contains:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Make sure you are using "post" as your form method as well.

Also, you seem to be trying to access `$_POST['sub']` when your code only shows the 'doc[]` input.

Comment: print_r($_POST); gives array()

Comment: If this still gives you trouble, please update your question with the entire HTML output of your form instead of the PHP code, and include the PHP you''re trying to use to access the post values. As-is, the code you posted is not a complete form.

Comment: im trying to fix a bug in someone else code. the form is really big!! if there is no other way to fix this, i will paste the entire code here.

Comment: @Phphelp: Then make sure to remove all the parts that are not necessary for someone to help, remove stuff like text, classes, non-form elements, etc. If it's really really big just post a link to a jsfiddle or pastie.

Comment: Hey Wesley Murch , Am getting error as `ReferenceError: $_POST is not defined` How can i solve that ?/

Answer (score 1):

that input should be inside form with method POST
`<form action="...." method="POST">
<input type="submit" name="sub" value="Delete_Checked"/>
</form>`

try to put the action to `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>"`

Comment: i have set method = "POST". :(

Comment: try to use action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>"

Comment: i wish.. but the whole page has 2832 lines! im trying to fix the bugs in someone else code...