# Uncaught ReferenceError: $_POST is not defined

Tags: php, ajax

I'm new in AJAX and want to send 2 IDs on an AJAX page here is my code

```
<a href="#" id="<?php echo $st_rows4['module_id'];?>" class="edit3">Click Here</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".edit3").click(function() {
        var moduleID    = $(this).attr('id');
        var studentID   = $_POST['studentAssignID']; //Problem is Here
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'assign-assignment-ajax.php',
            data: "moduleID="+moduleID+"&studentID="+studentID,
            success: function(data)
            {
                $("#editform2").html(data);
                $("#editform2").show('slow');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I'm getting module ID by clicking on a href, while I also want student ID with it, which part i'm doing wrong?

Comment: you cannot access the php variable $_POST in javascript like this, where did studentAssignID comes from? is it from a DB request or do you need this after the post is done?

Comment: You haven't wrapped the `$_POST['studentAssignID'];` in php, nor have you echoed like earlier.

Comment: show us your input form as well

Comment: why I'm getting -ve votes while i'm saying that I'm new to AJAX
@swidmann: i'm getting a student id from another ajax page it's not coming from direct DB

Comment: can you please provide more code, because I can't see the other AJAX call, and the point is, if it comes from an ajax call, how you can access it with post, is it all one file? I think there are more problems than just this:  $_POST['studentAssignID']

Comment: @swidmann: here is the flow something like that
student detail---> assignment status ---> assign assignment
getting id of student detail from DB ---> getting it on assignment status through ajax... also want this id from assignment status to assign assignment part using ajax

Comment: sorry without code, we can't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
var studentID   =  "<?php echo $_POST['studentAssignID']; ?>";
```

Comment: Perfect solution :) thanks a lot, this is what I want you are awesome

Answer (score 0):

Declare 'StudentAssignID' in hidden field.

```
<input type='hidden' class="StudentAssignID" value="<?echo $_POST['studentAssignID'];?>">
```

Then Use This Value in Script.

```
<script>
.
.
var studentID   = $('.StudentAssignID').val();
.
.
</script>
```